# Using php SDK with DynamoDB gives "STS_Exception", but works fine with S3

Tags: php, sdk, amazon-web-services

Server setup:

CentOS 6.2 64bit
Ngingx 1.2.1
PHP 5.3 + PHP FPM

I installed the SDK as a package through PEAR. I setup config.inc.php. I'm including the sdk with `require_once 'AWSSDKforPHP/sdk.class.php';`

I also setup my DynamoDB and have a table with some sample items.

If I do something like `$dynamodb = new AmazonDynamoDB();` I get the following error in the browser:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'STS_Exception' with message 'Temporary credentials from the AWS Security Token Service could not be retrieved using the provided long term credentials. It's possible that the provided long term credentials were invalid.' in /usr/share/pear/AWSSDKforPHP/sdk.class.php:763 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: CFRuntime->cache_sts_credentials(Object(CacheFile), Array) #1 /usr/share/pear/AWSSDKforPHP/lib/cachecore/cachecore.class.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #2 /usr/share/pear/AWSSDKforPHP/services/dynamodb.class.php(287): CacheCore->response_manager(Array, Array) #3 /var/www/picobama.com/public/canvas.php(14): AmazonDynamoDB->__construct(Array) #4 {main} thrown in /usr/share/pear/AWSSDKforPHP/sdk.class.php on line 763
```

However, if I initiate the S3 or EC2 class, there are no errors.

I even created a new key/secret combination to use in my config.inc.php thinking there might be something wrong with the default one, but didn't work.

I'm new to the SDK, I don't know what else to try, I would very much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there was a discrepancy between my server's time and the Amazon's server's time, which caused there to be an authentication error.

Fixed easily by installing/configuring NTP (Network Time Protocol).

See the url below for instructions in CentOS:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-install-ntp-to-synchronize-server-clock/